# existence of a unique function with property of equivalent to the exponential

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, real-numbers

Suppose that we wanted to prove that there exists a unique function $Exp:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $Exp(q)=exp(q)$ for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ where $exp(q)$ is the exponential function. How would we prove this? I know that the exponential function is uniformly convergent on the $\mathbb{R}$. Would it be sufficient to define $Exp$ as the the exponential form and show that for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have that $Exp(q)=exp(q)$? I can not think of any other way to prove it.

Comment: You cannot prove this. $f(x)=e^{x}$ for $x$ rational and $0$ for $x$ irrational would be  another function with this property.  However if you impose continuity then there is obviously only one function with this property.

Comment: The function is not unique. It would be unique, if you had some extra condition. It is unique if you say that it is monotone or continuous, for example

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How exactly would the imposition of continuity happen on the definition? My thought was to consider the instances where we have the condition satisfied and then glueing those continous instance as the defining domain for the function Exp.

Comment: @CalvinKhor apart from the continuous condition could we apply any other conditions such that we would have satisfaction?

Comment: Yes, I said one already, monotonicity. Or convexity (actually this is stronger than continuity so its not surprising). Or you can ask it to solve the ODE

Comment: It's definitely not true.  Consider $f(x)=\begin{cases}exp(x)&x\in \mathbb Q\\0&x\not \in \mathbb Q\end{cases}$, $g(x)=\begin{cases}exp(x)&x\in \mathbb Q\\x^2&x\not \in \mathbb Q\end{cases}$ and $h(x) =exp(x)$.  All three of those satisfy your conditions and are not unique.  No if you add then $Exp$ must be continuous then we must have $Exp(x)$ as $\lim_{q\to x;q\in \mathbb Q} exp(q)$ and that is only and therefore unique possible definition.

Comment: Since you seem to not be 100% clear on what we are saying - what we mean is that the following is true. "There exists a unique continuous function $\operatorname{Exp}:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $\operatorname{Exp}(q)=\exp(q)$ for all $q\in\mathbb Q$." (then, of course, $\operatorname{Exp}=\exp$). The same would hold true if we replaced 'continuous' with monotonic, convex, ...

Comment: Do you know what the definition of continuity means? Do you know that every real number has a sequence of rational numbers that converge to it and that every cauchy sequence of rational numbers converges to a real number?  With those in mind ....

Comment: "How exactly would the imposition of continuity happen on the definition?"  If $x \in \mathbb R$ then *by definition of the real numbers* there exists a sequence $\{q_i\}\subset \mathbb Q$ so that $q_i \to x$.  You function $Exp(x)$ is continuous it must be that $\lim exp(q_i)=\lim Exp(q_i)=Exp(\lim q_i)=Exp(x)$ and thus be unique.  However for this to be true we must prove that $\{exp(q_i)\}$ converges.  We can do that by proving it is cauchy.

Comment: @fleablood I am fairly new to this material, I understand what continuity means however I am not familiar with the property that every cauchy sequence of rational numbers converges to a real number. Is there a specific way to prove this? I know that exp(qi) converges as well, as I have proven that before.

Comment: @fleablood what if we started with the assumption that it was unique and continuous how would it be proven then ? at this point it would not seem necessary to prove the function converges

Comment: "however I am not familiar with the property that every cauchy sequence of rational numbers converges to a real number."  That is, more or less, the definition of the reals.  The reals are "complete" and has the "least upper bound property".