# existence of a function such that it is equivalent to cosine.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove there exist continuous functions $Cos : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Sin : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $Cos(q) = \cos(q)$ and $Sin(q) = \sin(q)$ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I have attempted this by noting that cosine and sine are continuous for all real numbers and therfore for the set of $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ we can hold that $Cos(q)=\cos(q)$ and that $Sin(q)=sin(q)$. I am not sure if this is sufficient however. Is correct or is there another way of showing this?

Comment: What is your question? $\cos, \sin$ are continuous.

Comment: related previous question and discussion in comments https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763861/existence-of-a-unique-function-with-property-of-equivalent-to-the-exponential

Comment: How did you define $\cos$ and $\sin$ for rationals?

Comment: My question is how can I prove that there exist a function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is equivalent to $\cos(q)$ for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ andthat there exist a function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is equivalent to $\sin(q)$ for $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ @copper.hat

Comment: I defined it as the regular cosine and sine function restricted to the rationals @user10354138

Comment: It feels like this is not the question you wanted to ask. Full proof for the question as stated: define $\operatorname{Cos}:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $\operatorname{Cos}(x) = \cos(x)$. Its continuous and agrees with $\cos$ on the rationals as needed. Similarly for sin. In fact the functions are unique because a continuous function is uniquely determined by its values on a dense subset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $Cos(x):= \cos (x)$ and $Sin(x):= \sin (x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ and you are done.